# Eigenvalues are the principal axis for m-dimensional paraboloid?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, neural-networks

From "Neural Networks - A Systematic Introduction" by [Raul Rojas chapter 8](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K8.pdf) (p. 188):

> $$E = ‖Xw−y‖^2= (Xw−y)^T(Xw−y)=w^T(X^TX)w−2y^TXw+y^Ty$$
>
> Since this is a quadratic function, the minimum can be found using gradient descent.
>
> The quadratic function E can be thought of as a paraboloid in m-dimensional space. The lengths of its principal axes are determined by the magnitude of the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix $X^TX$. Gradient descent is most effective when the principal axes of the quadratic form are all of the same length. In this case the gradient vector points directly towards the minimum of the error function. When the axes of the paraboloid are of very different sizes, the gradient direction can lead to oscillations in the iteration process as shown in Figure 8.1.

How does the author reach this ("The lengths of its principal axes are determined by the magnitude of the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix $X^TX$.") conclusion? Where can I read more about how this result is reached?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem

Comment: @Aretino Where can I read about it in more detail?

Comment: What is not clear in that page?

Comment: @Aretino how is it that the eigenvectors are the magnitudes of the principal axis?

Comment: That's not true: if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues, then the equation in the new basis is $\lambda_1 x^2+\lambda_2 y^2=1$, hence semi-axes have lengths $1/\sqrt{\lambda_1}$ and $1/\sqrt{\lambda_2}$.

Comment: @Aretino where can I read more in depth about the proof / understand better that fact?

Comment: Any linear algebra textbook should treat [matrix diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix), if that is what you need.

Comment: @Aretino I know diagonalization, but don't understand why the eigenvectors are the magnitudes of the principal axis of the paraboloid.

Comment: Did you read my comment above? The eigenvectors are NOT the magnitudes of the principal axis of the paraboloid, they are the reciprocal of the squares of the magnitudes. This is not in contrast with the book you cited: "are determined by" is not the same as "are equal to".

Comment: Okay, but where can I read the proof of that?

Comment: If you can find the length of the semi-axes from the equation, then what I wrote above and the example given by Wikipedia should be enough.

Comment: @Aretino "If you can find the length of the semi-axes from the equation" should I be able to easily obtain the length of the semi-axes from the given form of E?

Comment: I mean the new equation after the rotation, when the ellipsoid is axis-aligned. In that case you can easily read the lengths of the semi-axes from the equation.